# How to assign custom profile to custom domain users in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, asp.net-membership, sitecore8

I am trying to create a custom domain's user from code in sitecore 8.1. I am sucessfully able to create user using below code:

```
[HttpPost]
    public string RegisterUser(SurveyMonkeyUser userInfo)
    {
        string userId = "0";
        string Domain = "website"; //to be taken from config
        string ProfileItemId = "{7D473841-D585-43F6-9DF4-400313D945EC}"; //to be taken from config

        if (!AccountExists(Domain + userInfo.Username))
        {
            string domainUser = string.Concat(Domain ,@"\", userInfo.Username.Replace(" ",""));
            var user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Create(domainUser , "pass123");

            user.Profile.ProfileItemId = ProfileItemId;
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("FirstName", userInfo.FirstName);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("LastName", userInfo.LastName);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Email", userInfo.Email);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("DateOfBirth", userInfo.DateOfBirth);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Gender", userInfo.Gender);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Location", userInfo.Location);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Occupation", userInfo.Occupation);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("SectorEmployment", userInfo.SectorEmployment);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("Salary", userInfo.Salary);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("MaritalStatus", userInfo.MaritalStatus);
            user.Profile.SetCustomProperty("MobileNumber", userInfo.MobileNumber);

            user.Profile.Save();
            user.Profile.Reload();
            var username = user.Name;
            userId  = "Account Created Successfully " + user.Name;                
        }
        else
        {
            userId = "user already exist";
        }


        return userId;
    }
```

but it's custom properties are not visible in sitecore's backend but during debug i can see prevuiously created all user's profile using `Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(@"website\SyedAhsanJaffri",true).Profile.SerializedData` i got all properties

```
Count = 13
    [0]: {[digestcredentialhash, a287effab21c2ec84696e4eef4ca2171]}
    [1]: {[digestcredentialhashwithoutdomain, 767c0012faf8e872581d3ac5919db895]}
    [2]: {[FirstName, Syed Ahsan]}
    [3]: {[LastName, Jaffri]}
    [4]: {[Email, username@xxxxx.com]}
    [5]: {[DateOfBirth, 14/08/1985]}
    [6]: {[Gender, Male]}
    [7]: {[Location, Karachi]}
    [8]: {[Occupation, Software Engineer]}
    [9]: {[SectorEmployment, IT]}
    [10]: {[Salary, 351212]}
    [11]: {[MaritalStatus, Single]}
    [12]: {[MobileNumber, 923312190031]}
```

In back-end I have to change custom profile manually :) to view my properties.

Comment: did you create custom profile for this user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could open App_Config\Securiry\Domains.config and configure default profile item id there, e.g.:

```
<domain name="CommerceUsers" defaultProfileItemId="{0FFEC1BD-4D35-49CF-8B7D-7F01930834ED}" ensureAnonymousUser="false" />
```

P.S. However your code looks like correct. I wonder thy it does not work. Make sure that you transfer correct ID. Double check that you transfer ID of profile item from Core database(not the ID of profile template).

Comment: Thanks @Anton i was using template Id instead of profile item id.

Answer (score 2):

I normally use `user.Profile.SetPropertyValue("ProfileItemId", ProfileItemId);` instead of `user.Profile.ProfileItemId = ProfileItemId;`. Next to that the only difference I can see between your code and my (working) version is that I perform a save action (`user.Profile.Save();`) after setting the profile and before setting the custom properties.

Also, like Anton mentioned already: make sure the ProfileItemId is the ID of the profile item (located in /sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Profiles/...)